# URL Rewrite JSP

Tags: jsp, url, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I know this topic has been covered in lot of question but i could not find the right answer to my the issue i am facing. So it goes like this

I have a URL like this

```
localhost:8080/web/Area.jsp?name=food
```

I want to achieve the following for better SEO

```
localhost:8080/web/food-loc-hyd

Note: 
food is a input which has 1000's of variants like apple,dish,etc.

-loc-hyd is a static keyword and is added to every food
```

I tried URL rewrite filter from tuckey but I am not getting the correct combination. My name parameter above has thousands of different variables which can be given as input, so I tried something like this.

```
<rule><from>^/*-loc-hyd</from>

<to>/Area.jsp?name=*</to></rule>
```

I have a similar request which needs to be cleaned up which looks like this

from:

```
localhost:8080/web/Area.jsp?name=food&address=ind
```

to:

```
localhost:8080/web/food-loc-hyd/ind
```

Please guide on how to go about it.

Thanks , I am off to a start. I have done the above and its working to an extent. My navigation is like breadcrumbs structure so it goes like this

localhost/web/loc where loc is a variable so I have the following and it works:

```
Rule 1:
     <from>^/([^-]+?)</from>
     <to>/Area.jsp?name=$1</to>
```

Now when a user is on /hyd, I am sending him to /hyd/app and then to /hyd/app/lic where in both app and lic are variables so I did something like this:

```
Rule 2:
    <from>^/([^-]+?)/([^-]+?)</from>
         <to>/app.jsp?name=$1&app=$2</to>
```

Rule 1 and Rule 2 are working, but rule 3 below is not working, it is being handled by the  rule 1.

```
Rule 3:
    <from>^/([^-]+?)/([^-]+?)/([^-]+?)</from>
         <to>/lic.jsp?name=$1&app=$2&lic=$3</to>
```

Any ideas where I am not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url rewrite filters work via regex, and you need capture groups for the variables, not just a star.

Something like:

```
<rule>
 <from>^/([^-]+?)-loc-hyd/(.+?)$</from>
 <to>/Area.jsp?name=$1&address=$2</to>
</rule>
```

If you don't understand what that means, you need to study up on the [regex syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for Java.

Comment: Please check the edited question, its working for some urls but not for all.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution, I changed the order in urlrewrite.xml and have implemented it on my site http://www.citypincode.in

This is order which I have done in urlrewrite.xml and it is working fine:

```
<from>^/([^-]+?)/([^-]+?)</from>
         <to>/app.jsp?name=$1&app=$2</to>


<from>^/([^-]+?)</from>
     <to>/Area.jsp?name=$1</to>

<from>^/([^-]+?)/([^-]+?)</from>
         <to>/app.jsp?name=$1&app=$2</to>
```

Thanks for the help.